# Karate: How to send an Integer in Examples test data

Tags: api, automated-tests, frameworks, karate

```
{
"address" : <address>
}

Examples:
| address |
| 00247 |

And match $.address == <address>
```

I have above case where I need to pass 'address' attribute as integer and not a string.
But script passes it as 247 and not 00247.

`actual: '247', expected: '00247', reason: not equal`

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covered in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

Make this change:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def body = { address: '#(address)' }
* And match $.address == address

Examples:
| address! |
| 00247    |
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I tried same by appending ! in header i.e. address!, but still 247 is passed instead of 00247.
However when I tried without appending ! in header (and using '#(address)' in body), 00247 is passed. This solves the issue.
But another scenario that I wanted to verify is by passing null i.e. "address" : null.
Now in this case null is passed as String i.e. "null". How can we pass null not as String